# Where can I read/buy the 4-koma spin-off manga Baka to Test to Shoukanjuu Dya (or Baka to Test to Shoukanjuu Ja)?

Tags: baka-and-test

It appears that バカとテストと召喚獣ぢゃ (*Baka to Test to Shoukanjuu Dya* / *Baka to Test to Shoukanjuu Ja*) 4-koma spin-off manga was taken off the market some time ago, and there aren't any possible ways for me currently to be able to read it online.

Are there any possible ways that I can purchase the manga volumes?

Comment: i don't see a *Baka to Test to Shōkanjū Dya* on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baka_and_Test), closet i get is the manga *Baka to Test to Shōkanjū Ja*. you might also want to indicate what language you're looking for as i see some on [bookwalker](https://global.bookwalker.jp/series/24932/) and the preview look to be in english and i don't think they are *Baka to Test to Shōkanjū Ja*

Comment: It would probably be the same thing - Dya is an alternative (but fairly uncommon) romanisation of one form of Ja.

Comment: According to [Baka-Updates](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=49914), it hasn't been licensed in English yet, so there's no way to buy it in English...